# How can I run an Angular/Spring Boot app on AWS?

Tags: java, angular, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I was able to deploy my spring boot app by uploading a jar file with Beanstalk and got that running on a t2.micro instance successfully. Recently, I tried adding my Angular app to S3 and hosting that as a static website which was able to load but was causing CORS issues with the backend. Also, I was hoping to use ngrx Store within the Angular app, so a static website does not feel like a best practice or most efficient way to do that. Alas, this is where I have come to a bit of a dead end and I am seeking some advice.

Would anybody be able to offer tips on how to better deploy the Angular part of this project? Or any recommendations of a serverless approach would also be helpful. I have toyed around with the idea of using Lambda functions but after getting at least part of the project deployed using beanstalk I am admittedly a little reluctant to start from scratch.

I have also seen that possibly using a war rather than a jar could be helpful but can't find any great instructions on how to combine an angular and spring boot app into a war file (if that's even what exactly would happen).

I am more than happy to provide any additional information to help answer questions. Thanks in advance to any of those who are able to offer help!

Comment: What were the CORS issues? AWS gives you a few of options (static site with S3 which is probably the cheapest option or serving a static site/running ExpressJS on EC2/ECS/EKS) but S3 is probably the easiest and you may well get the same CORS issues whichever option you go with.

Comment: In your angular project , you need a file proxy.conf.json to direct calls to your services deployed in beanstalk.  For war file, you need to create a maven multi module project and create both backend and frontend maven child projects. There is a maven friendly end plugin , which builds n copies angular and copies to resources folder then create a war. I have developed a similar  war application and also separate angular and backend apps. Let me know you need any help specifically.

Comment: @tschumann The CORS issues I was running into came from simply trying to hit my backend that was deployed with beanstalk via the static site. You're right, I believe that the CORS issue will need be solved at some level no matter what but my main concern was that a static website would cause issues down the line as my application grows and becomes more dynamic. Would it make sense to have the angular app running in one EC2 instance while having my backend running in another? Or would it be better practice to package them?

Comment: @Vipul Could you tell me more about the specific maven plugin? It sounds like packaging everything into a war file to deploy with beanstalk would be the simplest route and being this is my first time doing this I was hoping to take the most simplistic approach possible. It sounds like what you built before was very similar to what I am working on. Would you mind if I invited you to a chat to ask some more specific questions?

Comment: @SteveEvrard I've got no strong opinions either way. In past things I've worked on they've always been separate so I'm not sure of the pros and cons.